# Adjusting Permissions to allow a python program to be able to update the time

Tags: python, windows, winapi, time

I have a python program that when it runs, it updates the time. (Has the same effect as hitting the "Update now" button.[image]

However, this means that either the program needs to get permission to do this, resulting in this popping up before allowing it to continue. [image]

I tried to change the permissions in windows settings but only got these very limited options, with the last one being the only one that didn't trigger the pop-up. This setting seems really unsafe to have on a pc and was wondering if I had any other options?

The code is (Current Python)

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time
import datetime
import win32api
import ctypes, sys

def Update_Clock():
    def is_admin():
        try:
            return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
        except:
            return False


    # List of servers in order of attempt of fetching
    server_list = ['ntp.iitb.ac.in', 'time.nist.gov', 'time.windows.com', 'pool.ntp.org']

    '''
    Returns the epoch time fetched from the NTP server passed as argument.
    Returns none if the request is timed out (5 seconds).
    '''
    def gettime_ntp(addr='time.nist.gov'):
        # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117211-simple-very-sntp-client/
        TIME1970 = 2208988800      # Thanks to F.Lundh
        client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
        data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
        data = data.encode()
        try:
            # Timing out the connection after 5 seconds, if no response received
            client.settimeout(5.0)
            client.sendto( data, (addr, 123))
            data, address = client.recvfrom( 1024 )
            if data:
                epoch_time = struct.unpack( '!12I', data )[10]
                epoch_time -= TIME1970
                return epoch_time
        except socket.timeout:
            return None



    if is_admin():
        # Code of your program here
        if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Iterates over every server in the list until it finds time from any one.
            for server in server_list:
                epoch_time = gettime_ntp(server)
                if epoch_time is not None:
                    # SetSystemTime takes time as argument in UTC time. UTC time is obtained using utcfromtimestamp()
                    utcTime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_time)
                    win32api.SetSystemTime(utcTime.year, utcTime.month, utcTime.weekday(), utcTime.day, utcTime.hour, utcTime.minute, utcTime.second, 0)
                    # Local time is obtained using fromtimestamp()
                    localTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
                    print("Time updated to: " + localTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + " from " + server)
                    break
                else:
                    print("Could not find time from " + server)

    else:
        # Re-run the program with admin rights
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

Comment: Not a programming question, voting to close.

Comment: I think the list of setttings is missing in your current post.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the OS time has serious consequences, it is normal that it requires permission.
I would not recommend to lower the security level of your system (especially if you intend to share this script). Running with elevated rights (admin) is the way to go.